# How to implement Python-like slicing in C++20 Ranges TS?

Tags: c++, range

[The ranges TS](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2018/p0896r3.pdf) has been merged into C++20. I was wondering what is the best way to implement Python-like slicing operations with that proposal? To be specific, assume `a` is a `vector<int>`, how to implement:

- `a[:5]`(first 5 elements)
- `a[5:]`(from the 5-th elements to the end)
- `a[2:4]`(the 2nd and the 3rd elements)
- `a[2::-1]` (a[2], a[1], a[0])
- `a[4:1:-2]` (a[4], a[2])

Comment: When will they start to merge something that matters before synthetic sugars :) Anyhow I bet bit better than boost ones: https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_37_0/libs/range/doc/examples.html  All I want to ask when concepts are coming :)) 2050? I remember they were rejecting designated initializers with similar reasons... Maybe we will get designated initializers when HalfLife3 comes and modules when HalfLife4 comes but we will get new named parameter idiom version 2.0 beta instead. I dont even bother standard sockets I lost all the hope already... Need to listen wasted years...

Comment: @Abdurrahim Concept is already approved and this proposal is heavily based on it. Designated initializer is also accepted (but only with the same order as declaration). Modules is "almost ready" and expected to get passed in the next meeting.

Answer (score 3):

Here are all the snippets I was able to come up to match your examples, please take these as hints as how to use the [current](https://github.com/ericniebler/range-v3) implementation of the TS.

```
std::vector<int> elements{0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9};

// First five elements
std::vector<int> a = elements | ranges::view::take(5);

// From the 5-th elements to the end
std::vector<int> b = elements | ranges::view::drop(5);

// The 2nd and 3rd elements
std::vector<int> c = elements | ranges::view::slice(2, 4);

// The first 3 elements, in reverse
std::vector<int> d = elements | ranges::view::take(3) | ranges::view::reverse;

// Elements 2-4 inclusive, reversed, and then taking every 2nd element
std::vector<int> e = elements | ranges::view::slice(2, 5) | ranges::view::reverse | ranges::view::stride(2);
```

Comment: A quick search in the proposal shows that only `take` and `reverse` exist in the proposal. No `drop`, `slice` or `stride` : (

Comment: Moreover, range-v3 does not support Concept. A more up-to-date implementation, as mentioned in the proposal, is [CMCSTL2](https://github.com/CaseyCarter/cmcstl2). Sadly the merged proposal varies from both of them in many ways. I can foresee another round of fragmentation.